# Avoiding "let mutable" cleanly with pattern matching and bitwise combining enum flags in fsharp

Tags: enums, f#, pattern-matching, mutable, bitwise-or

Consider the following (mutable) example:

```
let getRegexFlax flags =
    let mutable res = RegexOptions.None
    for ch in flags do
        match ch with
        | 's' ->  res <- res ||| RegexOptions.Singleline
        | 'x' ->  res <- res ||| RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
        | 'i' ->  res <- res ||| RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        | 'm' ->  res <- res ||| RegexOptions.Multiline
        | _   ->  raise (Exception("invalid flag"))
    res
```

I used this example to exemplify a situation we often encounter. The idea is simple: based on a string (or any complex condition), you need to combine zero or more enum flags.

The easiest way to do that, I think, is like above, with mutable. If you do not use mutable, I can think of a myriad of other ways, but none seem to be very clean:

- recursive function combining the return flags (cumbersome)
- [`enum.Combine`](http://hubfs.net/topic/None/56660) as Don Syme suggests, with an if-condition or pattern match in each array entry (ugly)
- a long range of `|||` combining expressions, each having a conditional (also ugly)

I'm sure there is a simpler, more direct way, preferably with pattern matching and, of course, without mutability. It may be the late hour of day, but I simply can't think of it at the moment, anybody can show me the light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
let chartoflag ch= 
    match ch with
    | 's' ->   RegexOptions.Singleline
    | 'x' ->   RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | 'i' ->  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | 'm' ->  RegexOptions.Multiline
    | _   ->  raise (Exception("invalid flag"))

flags |> Seq.map chartoflag |> Seq.fold (|||) RegexOptions.None
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Seq.fold` function (assuming that flags is a collection of chars)

```
let getRegexFlax1 flags =
    flags 
    |> Seq.fold (fun acc ch -> 
                    match ch with
                    | 's' ->  acc ||| RegexOptions.Singleline
                    | 'x' ->  acc ||| RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
                    | 'i' ->  acc ||| RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
                    | 'm' ->  acc |||  RegexOptions.Multiline
                    | _   ->  failwith "invalid flag") RegexOptions.None
```

Comment: Flags is a string in my example, which is a collection of chars, so this, which is essentially the same answer as John, but then inversed, would work as well. Question is, which is most readable ;).